# How do you write to the Log tab and Console.Error tab of the NUnit gui runner

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, winforms, nunit

In the NUnit Gui Runner, there are 6 tabs.  I can write to the Console.Out by writing something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("This will end up in the Console.Out");
```

I can write to the Trace tab by writing something like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("This will end up on the Trace tab");
```

But how do I write to the two other tabs, "Log" and "Console.Error"?

Comment: Note that these tabs have been combined with NUnit 2.5 into one tab named 'Text Output'.  You can configure which outputs are written to this window in 'Settings' -> 'GUI' -> 'Text Output'.  It is also possible to create new tabs if you'd like to separate things out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To write to Console.Error, you do this:

Console.Error.WriteLine("blah");

To write to the Log, you need to configure log4net in your test project, then setup a log4net appender in the .exe.config file for your project.  NUnit is actually a little tricky to setup with log4net, here's a little guide to get started:

http://www.softwarefrontier.com/2007/09/using-log4net-with-nunit.html

Comment: One user had a problem with this solution, and commented to use this [alternate solution](http://gaussc.blogspot.no/2009/02/configuring-nunit-tests-to-work-with.html) instead. And this worked in my scenario with VS2013 and a newer NUnit test framework.